# Parsing bundle from android push notification

Tags: android, json, bundle

I am using GCM to push notification to mobile using this [example](http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/) and the notification is pushed. But I could not able to parse the bundle received  from intent.
This is the bundle I got from log `Bundle[{message={"valid":"bbb","deal":"its working","address":"some","name":"aaa"}, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=198162727742}]`
.
and I converted it into string and then tried to convert to json object using this code`json = new JSONObject(message);` but no luck. can anybody tell what I am doing wrong here. thanks in advance

Comment: I found what's wrong I am sending bundle to another activity like this myintent.putExtra("message", extras.toString()).
It is converting to json correctly if I try in same activity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the method that received the intent do this:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //log the message in JSON format
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message >> " + intent.getExtras().toString());
    //Retrieve message and extra
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
}
```

Comment: But overrided method is `public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {` how to convert from bundle ?

Comment: in this case it would be `data.getString("message");`

Comment: `data.getString("message");` is not working for response.

Answer (score 2):

The real JSON Object is this:

```
{"valid":"bbb","deal":"its working","address":"some","name":"aaa"}
```

The rest is not actually JSON.

Try to parse just this line, and it will work =)

So:

```
json = new JSONObject( bundle.getString("message") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Bundle`'s built in functions to get data (`getString` for example). Try the following code:

```
String jsonStr = bundle.getString("message");
json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to take JSON value against "message" key and convert it into string

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
......

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            Log.i("Notification",
                    "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            Log.d(CabChainGlobal.APPTAG,
                    "Message received: " + extras.toString());
            sendNotification("" + extras.get("message"));
            Log.i("Notification Received", "Received: " + extras.toString());

        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
  }
```

.....